# Unable to scrape website: URL returned a bad HTTP response code

Tags: facebook, debugging, response, scraper

I noticed that this has been asked before, but no one else has yet to receive an answer, so I'll try my best to ask too.

In the last several months, my Wordpress website, http://geekvision.tv/ , has been undetectable by Facebook's debugger. I managed to get my homepage to work once or twice, but ALL of my posts are completely unregistered with the debugger, coming back saying that the og:url is not explicitely provided. For a link to a post on the site, you can find it here: http://geekvision.tv/2013/03/a-message-to-video-game-pirates/

Answer (score 1):

The [Facebook debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http://geekvision.tv/) returns the following error for your homepage:

> The object at 'http://geekvision.tv' previously had type 'article' and
>   cannot be changed to an object of type 'website' to avoid data
>   corruption of existing actions.

Try changing the og type back to `<meta property="og:type" content="article">`

For your other article, your webserver is returning a 404 error (despite then sending the full article).  You should fix this response header before getting Facebook to scrape your other pages.

```
HTTP/1.1·404·Not·Found
Date:·Thu,·09·May·2013·07:54:07·GMT
Server:·Apache
X-Pingback:·http://geekvision.tv/xmlrpc.php
Link:·<http://wp.me/p2eHBP-1Zz>;·rel=shortlink
Connection:·close
Transfer-Encoding:·chunked
Content-Type:·text/html;·charset=UTF-8
X-Pad:·avoid·browser·bug
```

Answer (score 0):

I find that if I use Chrome instead of Safari Facebook is able to scrape the images and does well. It's a simple answer to a problem I have been having for the last 4 months. Hope this helps.